# How can I obtain a rotation axis and angular velocity around that axis from angular velocities around the world coordinate axes?

Tags: linear-algebra, simulation, rigid-transformation

Say I am given the angular velocity of a rigid 3D object in the form $(\omega_x, \omega_y, \omega_z)^T$, where $\omega_x$ describes the angular velocity around the x-axis, $\omega_y$ around the y-axis and so on. Now from that I would like to obtain the 3D rotation axis and the angular velocity around that axis.

What I understood so far is that the rotation axis can be determined as the eigenvector with eigenvalue 1 of the infinitesimal rotation matrix $A$, which is defined as:

\begin{equation}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & - \omega_z & \omega_y \\
\omega_z & 1 & - \omega_x \\
-\omega_y & \omega_x & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

How can I now compute the angular velocity around that axis?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the velocity should simply be $\|\omega\| = \sqrt{\omega_x^2 + \omega_y^2 + \omega_z^2}$.

Comment: Is it really that simple? Could you explain why that is true?

Comment: I suspect that your definition coincides with the [usual definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_velocity#Particle_in_three_dimensions) of angular velocity. As they say in the article, $\omega$ is a vector whose direction is the axis of rotation and whose magnitude is the angular velocity about the axis of rotation

Comment: Indeed, this [later part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_velocity#Components_from_Euler_angles) of the article confirms that that components of the vector $\omega$ (as it is defined in the article) are the angular velocity about the $x,y,$ and $z$ axes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, @BenGrossmann! For some reason I did not realize that $\omega$ is always the eigenvector with eigenvalue 1 of $A$.

Comment: Actually, the matrix that you have written should not have an eigenvector associated with $1$. Should that instead be an eigenvector associated with $0$?

Comment: Multiplying $A$ with $\omega$ yields again $\omega$. So $\omega$ should be the eigenvector of $A$ associated with eigenvalue 1.

Comment: I see, that's correct. If we subtract an identity matrix, we can see that it is equivalent to say that $\omega$ is in the nullspace of
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & - \omega_z & \omega_y \\
\omega_z & 0 & - \omega_x \\
-\omega_y & \omega_x & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$